# How to render to multiple windows using a single OpenGL context?

Tags: c, opengl, glfw, openglcontext

I created two windows using GLFW. The first window has an OpenGL context and the second one doesn't. What I want to do is render the same scene to both windows using a single OpenGL context. Something like this.

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

// ... tell OpenGL to draw on first window

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(...);

// ... swap first window buffers

// ... tell OpenGL to draw on second window

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(...);

// ... swap second window buffers

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The problem is I don't know how to tell OpenGL to draw on a specific window. And I also don't know how to swap buffers for a specific window. If it's necessary, I can use Win32 API.

Comment: You don't tell OpenGL to draw to a window. When a context is made current, you provide an OS-dependent render target. That's what makes the association between a context and its window. GLFW prefers to own all this stuff, so as far as I can tell from a cursory examination of the docs, it doesn't let you do this. And if GLFW's NO_API window was not created correctly (with the right pixel format and such), then you can't attach an OpenGL context to its device context.

Comment: I've found a way to make this work. I create both windows with an OpenGL context. Then I use wglMakeCurrent(GetDC(glfwGetWin32Window(targetWindow)), glfwGetWGLContext(windowWithContext)) before glDrawArrays(...) and swap buffers normally with glfwSwapBuffers(targetWindow). Unfortunately, this method creates an additional unused OpenGL context.

Comment: @TudorLechintan: Alternatively, you could set up both context as _shared_ (GLFW explicitely supports that in it's API). In that case, you will have all the "heavy" GL objects like Buffers and Textures available in both contexts. Just the light-weight state containers like VAOs and FBOs are per-context, as are the "global" GL states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, GLFW does not directly support that in it's API. It generally considers a Window and a GL context as a unit. However, with the native APIs, you can do what you want. For windows 32 in partiuclar, have a look at [`wglMakeCurrent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd374387(v=vs.85).aspx). In GLFW, you can get the required context and window handles via [GLFW's native access API](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__native.html). Note that you will only get a `HWND` that way, you will have to manually use [`GetDC()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd144871(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the device context of the window.

Be aware that switching contexts will imply flushing the GL command queue, which can have negative effects on the performance. See [GL_KHR_context_flush_control](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/KHR/KHR_context_flush_control.txt) for more details.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Fortunately, flushing the command queue isn't a problem since my app stops rendering on the first window until the second one is closed. I wanted to implement something like a message box.